# constraint optimization in maximum likelihood estimate

Tags: maximum-likelihood

I have a sequence of iids defined by:

$f(x|\theta) = exp(-(x-\theta))\;\;\;\;  \theta<x<\infty$

To find the maximum likelihood estimate, i should maximize the log likelihood with respect to $\theta$. which is:

$Max (\sum -(Xi - \theta)) \;\;\;s.t \; \; \theta < min(Xi)$

which after introducing the lagrangian multiplier gives:

$Max \sum -(Xi - \theta) - \lambda(\theta - min(Xi)) $

how should i proceed from here? I cant figure how to take the derivatives

Comment: Try *drawing* the log-likelihood. You should simultaneously figure out why taking derivatives is no help, and where the likelihood will be maximized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that  $ \max (\sum -(X_i - \theta)) = \max (n\theta -\sum X_i)$.

It should be instantly obvious which $\theta$ maximises $ n\theta -\sum X_i$ subject to $\theta \le \min(X_i)$.